# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not method, trying to get an archive

Tags: json, python-3.x, class, typeerror, readfile

Im currently trying to build and app to manage budgets or expenses,
im new to python and everything really,
so im getting help from a friend, and im not quite familiarized with all the processes involved on coding.
So, i created a class for users, another for loading a list, and other to writte(inject) the list on a json that was created in the user class. I hope i was clear explaining.

this is the user code:

```
import os  
import json



class Usuario:

        def __init__(self,nombre):
            self.nombre = nombre
            self.verify_json()
            print(f"Te damos la bienvenida {self.nombre}")

            
        def get_nombre(self):
            return self.nombre
        
        def save_json(self,nombre):
            with open('data/'+nombre +"_usuario.json","w") as f:
                json.dump(self.nombre,f,indent=4)

        def verify_json(self):
            if not os.path.exists('data/'+self.nombre + '_usuario.json'):
                self.save_json(self.nombre)
                                
            else:
                with open('data/'+self.nombre + '_usuario.json', 'r') as file:
                    return json.load(file)
                    
                    
                
        def get_json(self):
            dir = 'data/'+ self.nombre + '_usuario.json'
            with open(dir, 'r') as file:
                return json.load(file)
```

I have changed this few times, because when i was calling the json file from another script i was getting the error that it wasnt a str.
Now, from here im calling it:

```
class w_jason():

    def __init__(self,archivo_json,lista_cuentas, nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.archivo_json = archivo_json
        self.lista_cuentas = lista_cuentas
        self.meses = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio',
                      'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre']
        
        self.archivo_user = self.leer_json()
        
    
    def listas_in_json(self):
        self.cuentas_dict = {self.lista_cuentas[i]: [] for i in range(len(self.lista_cuentas))}
        self.meses_dict = {self.meses[i]: self.cuentas_dict for i in range(len(self.meses))}
        return self.meses_dict
    
    def leer_json(self):
        with open(self.archivo_json, 'r') as file:
            return json.load(file)
       
    
    def edit_json(self):      
       with open(self.archivo_json, 'w') as file:
            json.dump(self.archivo_user, file, indent=4)
```

This class its receiving the path of the already created json archive, but im getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jabac/Desktop/work/proyecto_cuenta/scripts/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    m_json = w_jason(mariana.get_json, marian_cuentas.get_lista_cuentas, mariana.get_nombre)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jabac/Desktop/work/proyecto_cuenta/scripts/write.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.archivo_user = self.leer_json()
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jabac/Desktop/work/proyecto_cuenta/scripts/write.py", line 28, in leer_json
    with open(self.archivo_json, 'r') as file:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not method
```

So, I don't know what else to do. I was returning a str with the path of the file, but it was also giving me the same error, now I tried to just return the json file, and still get the error.

The app was working  minutes ago, and I don't know what i did that changed that behavior.

I'm sorry if this was too long, and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, sorry guys, i wasnt putting the () after calling the method.